# Changing a global variable in a function without using global keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: screenshot of code from a textbook]

Here is my code:

```
def L_value_Change(k):
    global L
    L = k
    return L

def  applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    L
    k = []
    for i in L:
       if g(f(i)):
          k.append(i)
    L = k
    L_value_Change(k)
    if L == []:
        return -1
    else :
        return max(L)
```

When I put this code, the grader tells me it's incorrect! So I read the introduction to the quiz, the instructor wrote "global variables don't work". How could I change the `L` variable with a function without using the word `global`? If you try my code and gave it the required input, it will give you a right answer, but the grader tells me it's wrong.

Comment: I guess people didn't like the picture but it seems like a reasonable question to me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Provide information as image iff they can't be posted as text (readable, searchable, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `global` keyword when you want to rebind the global variable to a different object. But you don't need it if all you want to do is change a mutable object. In your case `L` is a list and can be mutated in place with a slice operation `L[:] = k`. To demonstrate:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> 
>>> def L_value_Change(k):
...     L[:] = k
... 
>>> old_id = id(L)
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
>>> L_value_Change([4,5,6])
>>> assert id(L) == old_id
>>> L
[4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists are **mutable** objects, and as such, to change them all you have to do is just pass them as an argument to the function.

```
def f(i):
    return i + 2

def g(i):
    return i > 5

l = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    for val in L[:]:
        if not g(f(val)):
            L.remove(val)
    return -1 if not L else max(L)      

print(l) # [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
applyF_filterG(l, f, g) # Return 6
print(l) # [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code which avoids mutating on the list that you're trying to iterate upon.

```
def applyF_filterG(L,f,g):
        """
        Assumes L is a list of integers
        Assume functions f and g are defined for you. 
        f takes in an integer, applies a function, returns another integer 
        g takes in an integer, applies a Boolean function, 
            returns either True or False
        Mutates L such that, for each element i originally in L, L contains  
            i if g(f(i)) returns True, and no other elements
        Returns the largest element in the mutated L or -1 if the list is empty
        """
        # Applying the functions & Mutating L
        i = len(L)-1
        largestnum=0  
        if (len(L)==0):
            return -1
        else:
            while i>=0:
                if not g(f(L[i])):
                   del L[i]
                i-=1    

        #Finding the largest number
        if not L:
            return -1
        if (len(L)==1):
            return L[0]
        else:
            for num in range(len(L)-1):
                if (L[num]>L[num+1]):
                    largestnum=L[num]
                else:
                    largestnum=L[num+1]
            return largestnum
```